# MacOSX: @include

Tags: macos, awk

How does one `@include` awk files in Mac OSX?

Working code on Cygwin/Linux yields the following errors when run on mac:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 10 source file 
./program.awk
 context is
     >>> @ <<< include "/src/debug_functions.awk"
 13 extra )'s
```

Comment: `@include` is a gawk extension, are you running gawk?

Comment: @BenjaminW. ah that must be it.  was running awk on the pc but that must be using gawk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@include](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Include-Files.html) is gawk extension. Check the version of awk you have on both computers.

```
awk --version
```